# AngularJS pagination - wrong pages count

Tags: angularjs, pagination

look at the

plnkr.co/edit/fSLqieqjECEaF99mduub?p=preview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the page size to be 500 you need to add `items-per-page="500"`

```
<uib-pagination 
        total-items="bigTotalItems" 
        ng-model="bigCurrentPage" 
        max-size="maxSize"
        num-pages="noOfPages" 
        items-per-page="500"
        class="pagination-sm" 
        boundary-link-numbers="true"></uib-pagination>
```

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/TltntdMwDC0fL0ZlWrGa?p=preview).